# Binary search tree boolean return type

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

This is a function that add a node in my binary search tree.How can i reformat that to return true if  this tree did not already contain the specified element.

```
private Node insertNode(Node root, Student student) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(student);
    }
    int comp;
    if (Comparator != null) {
        comp = Comparator.compare(student, root.value);
    } else {
        comp = student.compareTo(root.value);
    }

    if (comp < 0) {
        root.left = insertNode(root.left, student);
    } else if (comp > 0) {
        root.right = insertNode(root.right, student);
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Extend your Node structure with additional status information - store here some meta information about node processing, e.g. "added, duplicated, updated"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refactor this code considerably if you want this.

It may be a lot simpler to first search for the node, if it exists, return false, and if not, run this code then return true. Something like:

```
// Keep `insertNode`, as is, unchanged, except name it `createNode`.
// Make sure to include in its docs that it doesn't create
// if the `student` record already exists in the tree.

private boolean insertNode(Student student) {
    if (search(this.root, student)) return false;
    createNode(this.root, student);
    return true;
}
```

As a general rule, you almost always want **2** methods when writing recursive algorithms. The actual recursive method, which is `private` and has nonsense arguments, at least when looking at it from an API perspective, and a `public` one, which knows which initial values must be passed for those arguments.

For example, in your code, you need to supply the `Node root` to `insertNode`. From the perspective of the `insertNode` recursive process this is crucial. However, from an outside perspective, this makes no sense. If I'm writing the code for the GUI frontend that shows all students, why do *I* need to supply the node? Your object surely is of type `StudentTree` or whatnot, *it* knows the root node, no doubt. (It should, e.g. by being a field, if it doesn't right now).

When you already have the double-method setup, you can also change the return type if you want.

To be clear, this is not feasible without making 2 methods. At best you can return, instead of `Node`, some combo object that returns the node as well as a boolean and then all callers can unpack it, but this requires a ton of effort (make a class to represent this, and *every time* you call `insertNode`, including in `insertNode` itself, unpack the Node object out).